# segmenting and writing binary file using Python

Tags: python, binaryfiles

I have two binary input files, `firstfile` and `secondfile`. `secondfile` is `firstfile` + additional material. I want to isolate this additional material in a separate file, `newfile`. This is what I have so far:

```
import os
import struct

origbytes = os.path.getsize(firstfile)
fullbytes = os.path.getsize(secondfile)
numbytes = fullbytes-origbytes

with open(secondfile,'rb') as f:
    first = f.read(origbytes)
    rest = f.read()
```

Naturally, my inclination is to do (which seems to work):

```
with open(newfile,'wb') as f:
    f.write(rest)
```

I can't find it but thought I read on SO that I should pack this first using `struct.pack` before writing to file. The following gives me an error:

```
with open(newfile,'wb') as f:
    f.write(struct.pack('%%%ds' % numbytes,rest))

-----> error: bad char in struct format
```

This works however:

```
with open(newfile,'wb') as f:
    f.write(struct.pack('c'*numbytes,*rest))
```

And for the ones that work, this gives me the right answer

```
with open(newfile,'rb') as f:
    test = f.read()

len(test)==numbytes

-----> True
```

Is this the correct way to write a binary file? I just want to make sure I'm doing this part correctly to diagnose if the second part of the file is corrupted as another reader program I am feeding `newfile` to is telling me, or I am doing this wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason to use the `struct` module, which is for converting between binary formats and Python objects. There's no conversion needed here.

Strings in Python 2.x are just an array of bytes and can be read and written to and from files. (In Python 3.x, the read function returns a `bytes` object, which is the same thing, if you open the file with `open(filename, 'rb')`.)

So you can just read the file into a string, then write it again:

```
import os

origbytes = os.path.getsize(firstfile)
fullbytes = os.path.getsize(secondfile)
numbytes = fullbytes-origbytes

with open(secondfile,'rb') as f:
    first = f.seek(origbytes)
    rest = f.read()

with open(newfile,'wb') as f:
    f.write(rest)
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on the use of `struct`.

Answer (score 3):

If you know that secondfile is the same as firstfile + appended data, why even read in the first part of secondfile?

```
with open(secondfile,'rb') as f:
    f.seek(origbytes)
    rest = f.read()
```

As for writing things out,

```
with open(newfile,'wb') as f:
    f.write(rest)
```

is just fine.  The stuff with `struct` would just be a no-op anyway.  The only thing you might consider is the size of `rest`.  If it could be large, you may want to read and write the data in blocks.

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't need to read `origbytes`, just move file pointer to the right position: `f.seek(numbytes)`
2. You don't need `struct` packing, write `rest` to the `newfile`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not c, there is no % in the format string. What you want is:

```
f.write(struct.pack('%ds' % numbytes,rest))
```

It worked for me:

```
>>> struct.pack('%ds' % 5,'abcde')
'abcde'
```

Explanation: `'%%%ds' % 15` is `'%15s'`, while what you want is `'%ds' % 15` which is `'15s'`

Comment: Ah, right, thank you -- but do you know if this is otherwise the correct way to segment a binary file?

Comment: @crippledlambda No idea, but it sounds like it will work, as long as the second file is just the first with more data on the end.